# How to convert a string to Date in Java?

Tags: java, date

I get a time string like "Thu, 11 Aug 2016 00:33:30 GMT".And I want to convert it to a Date object in Java.
I do it with the code:

```
String timeString= "Thu, 11 Aug 2016 00:33:30 GMT";
SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat
        ("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'", Locale.CHINA);
inputFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date date= null;
    try {
        date = inputFormat.parse(timeString);
        System.out.println(date.toString());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But I got a "java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: 'Thu, 11 Aug 2016 00:33:30 GMT'" exception.
Is everyone know why?Thanks a lot...

Comment: instead of 'GMT' try use z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `Locale.CHINA`. Aug is not in China language and changing it to `Locale.ENGLISH` will solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks,it's the problem....Locale.ENGLISH means which language use,not timezone..